# Hive Connectivity issue with connection string in Docker

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqlalchemy

I'm facing connectivity issues when i am trying to connect to hive through beeline or sqlalchemy. Otherwise it is working perfectly fine.

Problematic Beeline Command:

```
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

Problematic sqlalchemy Command:

```
hive://localhost:10000/default
```

I am able to connect to Hive otherwise by just entering `hive` in CLI or `!beeline !connect jdbc:hive2`

I am using below mentioned docker image:

https://github.com/suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive

Comment: Please show your docker command

Comment: please share the error code

Comment: The error is "Connection Refused"

Answer (score 0):

SqlAlchemy does not support natively Hive.

You need to install piHive to make it work. Can you provide you version of pyHive if installed or try to install it using

```
pip install PyHive
```

Comment: Already installed and resolve the dependencies. The error is "Connection Refused". Seems like Hive is using embedded mode to connect to the Hive Server 2 rather than Hive-Site.xml